# Gammu error insert to inbox

Tags: mysql, gammu

This MySQL query error happens when inserting into my `inbox` table.

> Error in SenderNumber column because value 'WENDY'S'.

How to edit the MySQL syntax for inserting into the inbox in Gammu?
I already tried this but this is not working: https://wammu.eu/docs/manual/smsd/sql.html#configurable-queries

```
Fri 2018/04/20 16:21:54 gammu-smsd[4760]: SQL failed: INSERT INTO inbox (ReceivingDateTime, Text, SenderNumber, Coding, SMSCNumber, UDH, Class, TextDecoded, RecipientID) VALUES ('20180420092816','00420065006C00690020004E0061007300690020002B0020004100790061006D002000430075006D0061002000520070002E00310038002E003100380032002000640069002000570065006E00640079002700730021002000540075006B00610072006B0061006E00200053004D005300200069006E00690020007300650067006500720061002000640069002000730065006C00750072007500680020006F00750074006C00650074002000570065006E00640079002700730021002000530026004B0020004200650072006C0061006B0075002E002000500072006F006D006F0020002A0036003000360023','WENDY'S','Default_No_Compression','+6281100000','','1','Beli Nasi + Ayam Cuma Rp.18.182 di Wendy\'s! Tukarkan SMS ini segera di seluruh outlet Wendy\'s! S&K Berlaku. Promo *606#','com6-simpati')
Fri 2018/04/20 16:21:54 gammu-smsd[4760]: Error code: 1064, Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'S','Default_No_Compression','+6281100000','','1','Beli Nasi + Ayam Cuma Rp.18.18' at line 1

Fri 2018/04/20 16:21:54 gammu-smsd[4760]: Error writing inbox message to database (SMSDMySQL_SaveInboxSMS)

Fri 2018/04/20 16:21:54 gammu-smsd[4760]: Error processing SMS: Unknown error. (UNKNOWN[27])
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a MySQL problem. Take a look at the query in your error log (with some formatting, and a long value removed for legibility):

```
INSERT INTO inbox (
    ReceivingDateTime
  , Text
  , SenderNumber
  , Coding
  , SMSCNumber
  , UDH
  , Class
  , TextDecoded
  , RecipientID)
 VALUES (
'20180420092816'
  ,'....'
  ,'WENDY'S'
  ,'Default_No_Compression',
  '+6281100000',
  '',
  '1',
  'Beli Nasi + Ayam Cuma Rp.18.182 di Wendy\'s! Tukarkan SMS ini segera di seluruh outlet Wendy\'s! S&K Berlaku. Promo *606#',
  'com6-simpati')
```

The value for `SenderNumber` is `'WENDY'S'`. The computer thinks the string ends after WENDY, then sees another character when it expected a comma and the next value. An error results.

You should escape the string: `'WENDY''S'` should do the trick.

Some official documentation about escaping strings in MySQL is [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-literals.html).

Comment: code is generated by gammu, where I can edit the query?